# Inserting into Postgres within a trigger function

Tags: database, postgresql, insert

I have a trigger function that I am running BEFORE INSERT on table1. In this function I do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(x, y, z);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(x, a);
```

For some reason, these INSERT statements do not run. I know that the function is being called.

UPDATE:

More information, my trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_db
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_all_db();
```

My procedure function doesn't do much. All I'm trying to do are a few statements as above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. Start with your trigger function, trigger, table definition, error messages, Postgres version and most importantly information about *any* other trigger involved.

Comment: I have asked for substantially more than the scarce information you added.

Comment: There are no error messages, this is Postgres 9.2. There are no other triggers. These are quite simply 3 arbitrary tables.

Comment: Try simplest mockup. Create another trivial table without any triggers etc and try to insert there.

Comment: Please show the **actual** trigger code from the function `update_all_db()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolons (`;`) are missing behind your statements.

And it is a suicidal move not to include a column list for your table in a persisted `INSERT` statement. If you change the table definition of `table2` or `table3` in the future, the trigger silently breaks or destroys data in the worst case. Should be:

```
INSERT INTO table2(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(x, y, z);
INSERT INTO table3(col1, col2) VALUES(x, a);
```

But that's no reason the statement should just "not run".
*This* problem is due to something that is *not* in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the semi-colons in the questions. I'll update the question with more details.