# Cannot create stored procedure to insert data: type mismatch for serial column

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id serial primary key, name text );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_insert_data( "name" text)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
INSERT INTO public.test values("name")
$$;
```

Error & Hint:

```
column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying
LINE 4: INSERT INTO public.test values("name")
                                       ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I followed this tutorial: https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/10-examples-postgresql-stored-procedures.
Obviously, I don't need to attach the column `id` for inserting.

Comment: `INSERT INTO public.test("name") values('name')`

Comment: The tutorial is incorrect. In Postgres identifiers e.g. table names are quoted with `" "` and string values use `' '`.  Also when you `INSERT` and don't include a column list to the table(public.test vs public.test(id, name)) then the  data in `VALUES` will assigned to the columns left to right. This is why you got `column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying`. If you are only inserting a subset of the columns then you need to specify them e.g `public.test("name")` . Another option is to do: `INSERT INTO public.test values(DEFAULT, 'name')`.

Comment: @wildplasser: You may be missing that the input parameter of the procedure is also named "name".

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Quotes are not the issue, the tutorial is not incorrect about *that*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no quoting issue, like comments would suggest.
And the linked tutorial is not incorrect. (But still bad advise.)

The missing target column list is the problem.
This would work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_insert_data("name" text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$proc$
INSERT INTO public.test(name)  -- !! target column list !!
VALUES ("name");
$proc$;
```

(For the record, since "name" is a valid identifier, all double quotes are just noise and can (should) be omitted.)

If you don't specify the target column(s), Postgres starts to fill in columns from left to right, starting with `id` in your case - which triggers the reported error message.

(The linked tutorial also provides an ID value, so it does not raise the same exception.)

Even if it would work without explicit target column list, it's typically still advisable to add one for persisted `INSERT` commands. Else, later modifications to the table structure can break your code silently. With any bad luck in a way you'll only notice much later - like filling in the wrong columns without raising an error.

See:

- [SQL INSERT without specifying columns. What happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884822/sql-insert-without-specifying-columns-what-happens/11885152#11885152)
- [Inserting into Postgres within a trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676214/inserting-into-postgres-within-a-trigger-function/16676847#16676847)

Aside: I would ***never*** use "name" as column name. Not even in a generic tutorial. That's not helpful. Any column name is a "name". Use meaningful identifiers instead.

Comment: I could not agree more. And, basically, even worse: there is no need for a function here.

Comment: @wildplasser In their defense, it's a procedure in a tutorial introducing procedures ...

Comment: And (pet-peeve of mine): use meaningless metasyntactic names and literals. (animals, flowers, fruits, ...)