# ERROR: syntax error at or near "END" when creating function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
> LINE 9:   END;
>           ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 350
> ===========================
> ```

My procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_insert(empid bigint,ename character varying(256),
                                        email character varying(256),enum bigint,
                                        eadd bigint)
                                      
 language 'plpgsql'
 as $$
 BEGIN
    insert into proc_insert(empid,ename,email,enum,eadd)
 END;
 $$;
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing semicolon after the command.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_insert(empid bigint
                                      , ename varchar
                                      , email varchar
                                      , enum bigint
                                      , eadd bigint)
                                      
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO proc_insert  -- add target column list!
   VALUES(empid,ename,email,enum,eadd);
END
$proc$;
```

(While the one after `END` is optional.)
Plus, your `INSERT` statement was broken anyway. I fixed it, but you better add a target column list, too. See:

- [Cannot create stored procedure to insert data: type mismatch for serial column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700309/cannot-create-stored-procedure-to-insert-data-type-mismatch-for-serial-column/68705067#68705067)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your insert query syntax is incorrect.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc_insert(empid bigint,ename character varying(256),
                                         email character varying(256),enum bigint,
                                         eadd bigint) 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    declare
    begin
       insert into proc_insert values(empid,ename,email,enum,eadd);
    end
$$;
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=45464af0617d93be37a9c92b0f6d97aa)

Comment: Without a column definition for the INSERT, this procedure will break when you create a new column for this table